# One large database table for my "list" or a new table for each "list"

Tags: database, schema

I'm trying to create a database system where users can create lists, and their friends (that they allow list access to) can add to the list.

I'm trying to map out this schema and can't decide between the following:

**List Table**
With attributes:
listid, entry-number, entry, user-id

Where listid is the list being changed, entry-number is the number of that entry in the list (so the first item in a list is entry 0), entry is the entry on the list, and user-id is the user who added the entry

VS

**Specific List Table**
where a specific table is made for each list with attributes
entry-number, entry, user-id

It seems like the 2nd option makes it much easier to get information/change a list once we find the table, whereas the first one is much easier to understand.

I'm just getting into databases so I want to pick the schema correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure but the second options does not make sense: it says that you will create a table for each list which it means that you are changing the schema every time you add data to you DB. Maybe I am not just getting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first option is more maintainable and normalised. It would be easier to query this option and create applications that use the list.

Comment: My question is if I have lots of users accessing one single list table, would this not be must less efficient (and slower?) than creating a separate table for each list? 

Is this scalable?

Comment: It will be more difficult to create an application that has to create a new table for each user. Suppose you wanted to find the user with the longest list for instance. How would you query that? It will not be any less efficient to use the single table. Database systems are optimized for exactly this type of scenario.

Comment: When you have 10000 users are you going to have 10000 tables in your database? That cannot be healthy.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, you should have two tables. One that holds user information and one that holds list information.
Users will have userID (PK) and your List table would have listID (PK) and a userID as FK to reference which user the list belongs to. So yeah, your first choice :)
GL

For example:

```
User
userID(PK) | username | etc
--------------------------
1 | Bob | etc
2 | Nick | etc


Lists
listID(PK) | userID(FK) | date_entered | entry
----------------------------------------------
1 | 2 | 1/2/2011 | blah blah
2 | 2 | 2/1/2011 | blah blah
3 | 1 | 2/3/2011 | blah blah
4 | 2 | 2/6/2011 | blah blah
5 | 1 | 3/1/2011 | blah blah

//you should know the userID for the user you are looking up list info for (C#)
query = "select * from Lists where userID = " + userID.ToString() + " ORDER BY date_entered DESC";
```

Comment: For each entry in a list, I need to track the user that made that entry. This doesn't seem faster with your setup.

Comment: @mamontazeri you will need to join the list items tabel with th euser table and you can get the details of the user.

Comment: The way I'm interpreting it is that I would need to split list into these 2 tables:

List
list-id | entry-number | entry

and, 


List-User
list-id | entry-number | user-id


This doesn't seem to make a huge difference.
Am I misunderstanding the way you would normalize this? Thanks!

Comment: You should take entry-number out. It would be too hard to keep track of that if you plan on deleting lists, etc. If you want to keep track of entry number, make a `datetime` column and order your queries by their dates.

Comment: Thanks Nick, entry-number is simply to sort the ordering, so this seems quicker.

Comment: the goal of normalizing here is to group certain data together in separate tables and reference them with their PKs and FKs.

Comment: So let's say I ALWAYS want to display the lists in sorted order. Would `list-id` | `datetime` become my primary key?

How would that be trackable when deleting lists? Thanks

Comment: Also, I reread your original post. I completely and utterly misread it. We were agreeing the entire time. Regarding datetime, I'm still curious though. Thanks

Comment: Cool, I edited my answer :) the order your rows are returned is going to be the order they were entered starting with the most recent according to my query ex